# Date is invalid on POST, but valid when I GET the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, globalization

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC view based on a model. This model has the following property:

```
    public DateTime PaymentStartDate { get; set; }
```

When I enter my view in the GET method, the value of `PaymentStartDate` is 31th of March (31/3/2018 23:59:59).

In my view, I do the following:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PaymentStartDate)
```

Which is rendered as follows:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field PaymentStartDate must be a date." data-val-required="The PaymentStartDate field is required." id="PaymentStartDate" name="PaymentStartDate" type="hidden" value="03/31/2018 23:59:59" />
```

But when I POST to my endpoint, my modelstate is invalid because:

```
The value '03/31/2018 23:59:59' is not valid for PaymentStartDate.
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

If I pick a date, such as `3/12/2018`, it works. So my assumption is because I have a Danish machine (using dd/MM/yyyy format), it gives some problems.

Any ideas or hints what I can do here?

Comment: Always use ISO8601 notation for Date and DateTime values, specifically when you store values as strings (like in the HTML) and when sending values between 2 end points (like browser and server).

Comment: Yes that's likely to be it. Use an unambiguous date format such as ISO8601. Ps 03/12/2018 might "work" but the server will think you meant 12th March not 3rd December, so it may not work _as you expected_.

Comment: I would say always use Unix timestamp if you don't need to display it. 0 ambiguity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation for `Date` and `DateTime` values. Specifically when you store values as strings (like in the HTML in a hidden input field) and when sending values between 2 end points (like between browser and server).

That way there is no ambiguity regardless of client or server culture.

Example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PaymentStartDate.ToString("o"))
```

See also [The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)

Comment: Makes sense! So in ASP.NET MVC, I guess that's adding ".ToUniversalTime();" ? :)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - no, that is UTC which has to do with *when* a time occurred. It is also recommended to transfer dates and datetimes as UTC so there is no ambiguity on when something actually occurred regardless of timezone.

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard - [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) deals strictly with how to *format* the Date / DateTime as a string so it can be parsed/read and always have the same value regardless if the client machine is set to Japanese, British, US, etc culture